# Chart.js não aparece no html

Tags: javascript, chartjs

Bom dia pessoal, recentemente resolvi implementar o chart.js em alguns projetos meus, porém ele não me exibe os dados.

Estou deixando abaixo o código fonte de testes que não é exibido.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>
<!-- CHART JS IMPORT -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("line-chart")

  // Type, Data e options

  var ChartGraph = new chart(ctx, {

    type:'line'
    data:{
      labels: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun","Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Taxa de Cliques - 2020",
        data: [5,10,5,14,20,15,6,14,8,12,15,5,10],
        borderWidth: 6,
        borderColor: 'rgba(77,166,253,0.85)',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      }]

    }
  })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem dois erros no código:

- deve usar `new Chart` e não `new chart`, veja a documentação: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/
- os parâmetors estão mal formatados, falta uma vírgula aqui: `type:'line',`

```js
var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("line-chart")

var ChartGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:'line',
    data:{
      labels: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun","Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Taxa de Cliques - 2020",
        data: [5,10,5,14,20,15,6,14,8,12,15,5,10],
        borderWidth: 6,
        borderColor: 'rgba(77,166,253,0.85)',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      }]

    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Valeu irmão, resolveu meu problema!

Comment: boa, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta ;)